# What is the best way to implement Linux command diff using any java API?

Tags: file, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, java

I need to find the difference between two files in terms of lines.
Lets say I have 2 files: file1.txt and file2.txt.

File1 has the lines:

```
LINE A
LINE B
LINE C
```

File2 has the lines:

```
LINE C
LINE D
LINE E
```

Now lets say I want to find the difference between file2 and file1 (i.e (file2)-(file1) ). Then as my result I should be able to get:

1. The lines that appeared in file2 but not in file 1. In my example this would be: `LINE D` and `LINE E`.
2. The lines that appeared in file1 but not in file2. In my example this would be: `LINE A` and `LINE B`.

It is easy to implement this requirement using diff command of Linux.
But now somehow I need to implement this using Java. While it is easy to implement the solution using **brute force** comparison of lines of both the files, it is extremely **bad in terms both time and space complexity**.
As my file can have as many as **millions of lines** such implementation is **not scalable**. So I am looking for any Java API that provides such functionality as well as scalability when it comes to such big files.

Comment: You could use Runtime#exec to run the diff command (or fc on Windows)

Comment: Why? `diff` already exists. It's a non-trivial program. You shouldn't have to reinvent it.

Comment: I am not running a Linux machine. And also I am facing other problems while running Linux commands on Windows. So I need to execute them using Java only. I have seen multiple open source java API but am not sure which one of them will be the best for my requirement ? Please help.